Getting a +5 V supply from a negative 48 V , non-isolated (Telecom)
I'm trying to get a positive 5V supply, with < 1 A of out current starting from a -48 V. I need no isolation between the two, so no transformer.
I've read this TI article :
https://www.bing.com/search?pglt=929&q=parralel+universe+of+negative+input+voltage&cvid=f3fa9379703342b18d6df8772ae713a1&gs_lcrp=EgRlZGdlKgYIABBFGDkyBggAEEUYOdIBCDU4MzRqMGoxqAIAsAIA&FORM=ANNTA1&PC=U531
Understanding that some problem arises for the Internal Vcc of the controller and for the feedback.
I have tried to use the LT8365 (*) controller as a boost topology in DCM to get 53V out of 48V, with 5 V over the gnd common top rail, using a level shifter for the feedback, in this way:

But what i obtain at the output is 1.75 V with some ripple, like this:

Beside the values of the passive component, is there any issues about the level shifter or the controller that I'm still missing? Maybe is it better to use an inverting buck-boost configuration?
(*)
The LT8365 can be configured as boost, sepic or inverting, with wide Vin range up to 60 V, it has an internal switch 150 V 1.5 A, that fits my requirements, but I can't work it out

What is the purpose of the Q1 and U2?

Level shifting the feedback, two different reference are used for the controller and the output

Why is this needed if you are trying to produce 53 volts? Is it to do with accuracy of the 5 volt difference?

Maybe i'm getting something wrong, I'm trying to getting 5V out of a -48V, so the idea is to make it work as a boost, providing the feedback needed, (from datasheet 1.6V), but since the ref for the controller is -48V, the feedback needed is -46.4V, since I'm taking the output referred to the 0V, i can't get the required feedback in other way

Yes I can see what you are trying to do now. Somewhere around the PNP transistor there has to be a wrong value. I suspect that your reliance on the RH1009 may have something to do with this because it doesn't start properly regulating until it is conducting 0.4 mA. Maybe try simulating that one little section to see if it reveals anything.

I've seen that the RH1009 is not working properly, you're right, but i cannot understand why, changing the Re of pnp at 5k the lt8365 seems to be working, but only at very low current, and still not getting the RH1009 working, i see across it -0.7V instead of the 2.5V

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

There are inverting DC-DC topologies as well that can convert -48V to +5V directly (or any other positive voltage no matter whether smaller or larger than 48V)

@giumus - Hi, You posted a self-answer, but it was asking more questions, That is not allowed on Stack Exchange, since questions & answers must be in different places here. || If (as it seems) you now have a follow-on question, then first please review the answers here to the original question & consider upvoting/áccepting, as appropriate, to effectively conclude this question. Then you can ask a new question about your new design. Any new question should be self-contained and not require people to read this one, but should include a link to here for context. TY

A small isolating DC-DC converter module, with 36V-72V input range, and 5V 1A output is the easiest approach. -48V to negative input, 0V to positive input.  Then connect the 0V output to 0V input, and you're good to go.
I've used this exact approach in a number of commercial telecoms applications. These modules are cheap, small (as they typically use high switching frequencies), and are available with a range of fault protection / control options.
Cost from about $5 for a cheap Chinese module, to about $20 for a unit from a brand name such as Murata.
(The 36V-72V voltage range is typical for telecom kit, and covers the absolute minimum voltage + margin of a nominal "48V" supply when the battery bank is fully discharged, up to the absolute maximum for the rare 60V exchanges + margin during an equalize operation. However, a narrower range of 40V-60V is very unlikely to cause any issue.)

Thanks for your answer. I have to measure the current at the RTN path of the GND rail, with a current sense amplifier powered by this supply, if they are isolated, they refer to two different gnd, make it tough? Or am I good to go? There will be higher CMRR requirements?

You are good to go.  The 5V supply is not isolated, because you are connecting the 0V/-ve output to the 0V/+ve input rail.  The use of an isolated DC-DC converter merely allows you to shift the output supply "ground"/0V reference to the input +ve/0V instead of the -ve/-48V.

Thank you, do you have any design example or some documentation i can refer to?

The designs are commercial, but I can confirm from experience the Recom REC5-4805 converters, and their Murata equivalent have been used in production for a very similar telecoms application for many years without issue. These are not the cheapest units, but we selected for long term reliability.,  and low recall/return costs.

Consider the LT8709, which is designed to be used for a variety of negative-input functions--including this typical application that's almost exactly what you want:

You will need to modify this slightly to make it work with -48 V in, but the chip itself is fine with inputs as low as -80 V; I'm not sure exactly what the limiting factor is that makes this example application only suited for up to -42 V. Probably safety margin on either the (50 V rated) input capacitors or possibly the (60 V rated) MOSFET, both of which could be easily exchanged for higher-voltage ones.

Hi, thanks for the suggestion! I have already seen the LT8709, and also tried this configuration on LTspice, but something went wrong, I have concluded that 5/48 is a very small, less than 10% Duty cycle, and cannot work, if I'm not wrong in this application the controller is working in CCM, maybe forcing DCM is better. Although, I'm trying hard to use the LT8365, since it does not require any external MOSfet, and it is way less cheaper, but if I can't work it out, maybe I have to use the 8709. In this case, it is possible to use only the Nmos, instead of the syncrhonous version with both ?

@giumus There's nothing wrong with using a converter at a low duty. The only actual limit is the minimum on-time of the controller, which in the case of the LT8709 is no greater than 420 ns. What duty this corresponds to depends on the switching frequency you choose; it may be an issue if you want to run this converter at 500 kHz where the minimum duty would be 21%, but if you run it at 100 kHz, your minimum duty becomes 4.2% and you should have no problem getting -48 V to +5 V conversion.

Ok understand! That's great, thanks a lot for the clear explanation! So, at 100 KHz, i can work with 9.4% to get an inverting buck-boost in CCM, is it right? Plus, is there a way to get rid of the synchronous driving pmos, and its sense resistor with a diode, or are them mandatory?

Following the step design for Inverting on LT8709 datasheet pag.18, at step6 I find a Ltyp value of 108 uH, is it feasible? And doing the calculation for Lmin I've obtained a negative value, I think I'm still getting something wrong..

@giumus 108 μH sounds like a reasonable number for a mid- to low-frequency converter. A negative value for Lmin just means that your control loop will be stable with any inductance; you don't need to consider the slope compensation a limiting factor here. 9.4% sounds about right, and the sync FET should be fine to replace with a diode if you don't care about the efficiency drop. I am unsure if it will operate with Rsense2 omitted; try it and see? Most LT parts have very good simulation models, so you can just try it in simulation, too.

Here's the LTspice sim of the LT8709 suggested by Heath:
The parts were selected to give a 5V output, but they may not all be the best values, so you should look at the data sheet to determine the optimum values.


Thanks a lot for the suggestions. As said, I was hoping to not get into the 8709, that is more expensive, and need Nmos and Pmos, with two sense resistor. But, if it is not possible to use the 8365, I will take this solution, is there a way to not use a syncrhonous version, cutting the Pmos and its relative sense resistor? Have you configured the 8709 to work in which mode? I have to stay below 150 KHz of switching frequency, due to the telecom environment

Is C10 upside down? Or am i wrong?

Yes, C10 is upside down.  I forgot to change it when I modified the example circuit in LTspice  to give a positive output.
